# Replacement for UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification deprecated API from Apple

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, deprecated

I'm looking for a replacement to UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification but I haven't found any so far. Where does Apple store this info?

Here's the official docs link - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623018-didchangestatusbarframenotificat

Comment: The source states "Use viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: instead". What are you trying to do exactly? Some context might help to find an alternative.

Comment: @wvteijlingen what did you mean by source? Is it the link I attached? If yes, I can't see that replacement info anywhere in that web page. Can you help me find it?

Comment: Also, @wvteijlingen I'm trying to get the status bar current orientation(depending on portrait or landscape) to handle some business logic in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: instead.